# CodeIgniter 3 Session not working on Safari

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, safari

I got a problem with the CodeIgniter session when users use Safari from PC or Tablet. On Google Chrome and Firefox Dev Edition is working perfectly i think the problem is related with Safari.

That's my code for the session after the success log-in:

```
$logged_in = array(
    'username' => $out[0]['username'],
    'user_id' => $out[0]['id'],
    'logged_in' => TRUE
);
$this->session->set_userdata($logged_in);
$this->session->set_flashdata('user_data', $logged_in);
redirect('social/userprofile/' . $out[0]['username']);
```

The problem is when a user try to login in the website with Safari he is redirected again on the login page.

This because:

```
public function check_logged($user2=""){
     $check_session = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
     if(!$check_session) {
       redirect('social/index');
     }
}
```

Trying a log-in with session saving the session as a file i've see the session create 4 file 3 empty and one with the right information of the session data.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the error your getting?

Comment: the user is redirected again to the login page because during the redirect to the user profile there aren't the session data.

Comment: Please update your code with the login function..also the user profile where you check for session cookie.

Comment: The problem is not in the code the problem is Safari and CI Session. I don't know why.. all the code is perfectly working under Chrome and Firefox but on Safari don't set the session.

Comment: How do you use `$user2` parameter in that method?

Comment: $user2 is used to load different data in a sidebar in a particular case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things,

**CodeIgniter**  `$this->session->userdata('user_id')` returns **Boolean** for this, So you cannot check whether its **empty**. You have to check whether its **true** or **false**.

Change this:

```
public function check_logged($user2=""){
  $check_session = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
     if(empty($check_session)) {
       redirect('social/index');
}
```

To

```
public function check_logged($user2=""){
  $check_session = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
     if(!$check_session) {
       redirect('social/index');
}
```

Comment: Yes that's true i've updated this portion of code but the problem persist on Safari

Comment: I'm also saving the sessions as file. With Chrome and Firefox the session is  saved but with Safari the session is empty

Comment: Yes it's OK i've just see Chrome is generating 1 file where save session info data, Safari is generating 3, 4 or more then 5 files 1 with all session data and the others are empty..

Comment: i've also see some one with same problem have fixed setting hwclock to right data and time but mine is correct.. I'm going crazy i'm the only one with this problem ??

Comment: sure: have a look on beta.wardrobe.net u can make a signup using this invitation code: Priscilla

Comment: @mds i just checked. it's not working both on IE and Safari....I think it's an issue in your server side

Comment: i've found some one with same problem but related with hwclock but mine return the right time: 
root@mdslab ~ # hwclock -r
Sun 04 Oct 2015 04:40:25 PM CEST  -0.520593 seconds

what i can do? :(

Comment: @mds goto your `config.php` and change the **session cookie** name to `cisession`

Comment: I've try also this but with no happy results.. the funny things is: Safari and IE session are working perfectly on same server with same code but CI 2.2 !!

Comment: @mds again goto `config.php` and `sess_match_useragent` make this false;

Comment: on old configuration file was set on TRUE i've try all both true or false but nothing change :|
This is my config

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/var/www/vhosts/wardrobe.net/beta.wardrobe.net/sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;

Comment: and this is the config for cookies: 

$config['cookie_prefix'] = 'mw';
$config['cookie_domain'] = 'beta.wardrobe.net';
$config['cookie_path']  = 'noway/cookies/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

Comment: I've found the problem! Was the cookie_prefix and domain and also cookie path thanks for your incredible patient and help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91307/discussion-between-mds-and-jlocker).